# Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I've written a custom Google Apps Script that will receive an `id` and fetch information from a web service (a price).

I use this script in a spreadsheet, and it works just fine. My problem is that these prices change, and my spreadsheet doesn't get updated.

How can I force it to re-run the script and update the cells (without manually going over each cell)?

Comment: For those encountering similar (defined and logical, but sometimes unfortunate) behavior, it might help to go upvote this feature request in Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763858.

Comment: Here is a [simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172809/google-sheet-update-source-in-script/60189296#60189296) I did.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Ok, it seems like my problem was that google behaves in a weird way - it doesn't re-run the script as long as the script parameters are similar, it uses cached results from the previous runs. Hence it doesn't re-connect to the API and doesn't re-fetch the price, it simply returns the previous script result that was cached.

See more info here(Add a star to these issues, if you're affected):

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753882
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763858

and [Henrique G. Abreu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9023954)

My solution was to add another parameter to my script, which I don't even use. Now, when you call the function with a parameter that is different than previous calls, it will have to rerun the script because the result for these parameters will not be in the cache.

So whenever I call the function, for the extra parameter I pass "$A$1".
I also created a menu item called refresh, and when I run it, it puts the current date and time in A1, hence all the calls to the script with $A$1 as second parameter will have to recalculate. Here's some code from my script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Refresh",
    functionName : "refreshLastUpdate"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Refresh", entries);
};

function refreshLastUpdate() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A1').setValue(new Date().toTimeString());
}

function getPrice(itemId, datetime) {
  var headers =
      {
        "method" : "get",
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        headers : {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
      };

  var jsonResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://someURL?item_id=" + itemId, headers);
  var jsonObj = eval( '(' + jsonResponse + ')' );
  return jsonObj.Price;
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

And when I want to put the price of item with ID 5 in a cell, I use the following formula:

```
=getPrice(5, $A$1)
```

When I want to refresh the prices, I simply click the "Refresh" -> "Refresh" menu item.
Remember that you need to reload the spreadsheet after you change the `onOpen()` script.

Comment: why not using now() as an additional parameter?

Comment: You see, just like my function will not be re-evaluated because it's parameters haven't changed (ie the values of the cells), now() will not be re-evaluated either since it has no parameters, hence it's return value will not change and so my function's parameters will not change. Also, using now() would cause my function to re-evaluate all the time which is a bit heavy considering that it generates several HTTP calls...

Comment: Good find. I had this problem while using named ranges as input. Using your answer, I figured out it's often good enough to pass a dummy sum over the range of inputs, as in "sum(B:D)", where rows B-D are in the range looked up by the custom function. Changing any cell will trigger the sum to change and the custom function to refresh. By the way, it seems the custom function does not even have to declare the ignored parameter.

Comment: A shame that this is still the best solution I found to this problem. Rather than Google just allowing us to disable cache for particular function calls, we arbitrarily increase what is being stored in the cache just to make sure we don't get a cached value... Still, thanks for post,

Comment: Try using a parameter for your custom function [like this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172809/google-sheet-update-source-in-script/60189296#60189296)

Comment: Looks like `addMenu` is deprecated: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: Conveniently, you **don't** need to add the parameter to the script. So you can leave the script as `function getPrice(itemId)` and just call it as `=getPrice(5, $A$1)`. The extra argument seems to be ignored. For me, this is best. All I then do is type a single character into `A1` to trigger a refresh. As quick as using a menu item and more convenient to setup.

Answer (score 46):

You're missing the fastidious caching <s>bug</s> feature. It works this way:

Google considers that all your custom functions depend **only** on their parameters values directly to return their result (you can optionally depend on other static data).

Given this prerequisite they can evaluate your functions only when a parameter changes. e.g.

Let's suppose we have the text "10" on cell B1, then on some other cell we type `=myFunction(B1)`

myFunction will be evaluated and its result retrieved. Then if you change cell B1 value to "35", custom will be re-evaluated as expected and the new result retrieved normally.
Now, if you change cell B1 again to the original "10", there's no re-evaluation, the original result is retrieved immediately from cache.

So, when you use the sheet name as a parameter to fetch it dynamically and return the result, you're breaking the caching rule.

Unfortunately, you can't have custom functions without this amazing feature. So you'll have to either change it to receive the values directly, instead of the sheet name, or do not use a custom function. For example, you could have a parameter on your script telling where the summaries should go and have an `onEdit` update them whenever a total changes.

Comment: Hmmm, that is annoying, but thankyou for the answer! I have got a nasty workaround by adding a dummy parameter to the function; if I then pass a cell reference to that I can force the data to refresh by just incrementing a number in that cell. Don't suppose there is anyway I can create a refresh button that will do that on a click, is there? That would be fine, it doesn't need to be automatic really, just easy and obvious.

Comment: Well, you can create a button, actually a drawing and assign an script function to it, that will increment you dummy parameter cell that will force the update.

Comment: "For example, you could have a parameter on your script telling where the summaries should go" - what summaries?

Comment: You can invalidate the cache by [storing a `value` in the cell, then storing the formula again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77391841/1269037).

Answer (score 38):

What I did was similar to [tbkn23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347290). This method doesn't require any user action except making a change.

The function I want to re-evaluate has an extra unused parameter, $A$1. So the function call is

```
=myFunction(firstParam, $A$1)
```

But in the code the function signature is

```
function myFunction(firstParam)
```

Instead of having a Refresh function I've used the onEdit(e) function like this

```
function onEdit(e)
{
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(Math.random());
}
```

This function is triggered whenever any cell in the spreadsheet is edited. So now you edit a cell, a random number is placed in A1, this refreshes the parameter list [as tbkn23 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347290), causing the custom function to be re-evaluated.

Comment: Works great.  Downside is, undo (ctrl+z) history is messed up.

Comment: Nice trick with an annoying downside as Jon pointed out... I hope someone will improve it :-)

Comment: Small and pedantic caveat with this answer; in the incredibly unlikely event Math.random returns the same number, on that occasion it will not update, as that particular number has already been cached.

Comment: Doesn't work at scale and in highly dynamic situations unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

There are settings where you can make `NOW()` update automatically:

[image]

Comment: `NOW()` is a built-in function, not a custom function.

Comment: @Rubén The point is you could include NOW() function in any custom function you want to have it update

Comment: At this time custom functions arguments should be deterministic, in other words, they don't allo NOW() as argument. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: It throws an error if you try to use NOW() inside a custom function

Answer (score 7):

If your custom function is inside a specific column, simply order your spreadsheet by that column.

The ordering action forces a refresh of the data, which invokes your custom function for all rows of that column at once.

Comment: only works if the sheet isn't already ordered

Comment: This is a particular case of asking the user to make a pervasive change to the sheet. It's simpler to insert a blank first row, then delete it, actually. But a good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet/77391841#77391841) would require less or no user intervention.

Answer (score 7):

#### Script Logic:

- Custom Functions don't update unless it's arguments changes.
- Create a `onChange` trigger to change all arguments of all custom functions in the spreadsheet using `TextFinder`
- [The idea to add a extra dummy parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347290/) by @tbkn23  and [use of the triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27656313/) by @Lexi Brush is implemented here with a random number as argument. This answer mainly differs due to usage of class `TextFinder`(a relatively new addition to Apps script), which is better because

  - No extra cell is required.
  - No menu is needed > No  additional clicks needed. If you need a custom refresher, [a checkbox is a better implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64711064/)
  - You can also change the [formula itself instead of changing the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61946592/)
  - The change/trigger can be configured to filter out only certain  changes. For eg, the following sample script trigger filters out all changes except `INSERT_GRID/REMOVE_GRID`(Grid=Sheet). This is appropriate for the custom function that provides `sheetnames`. A edit anywhere isn't going to change  the list of sheets/sheetnames, but inserting or removing sheet does.

#### Sample custom function(to refresh):

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 * @returns Current list of sheet names
 */
const sheetNames = () =>
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheets()
    .map((sheet) => sheet.getName());
```

#### Refresher function:

```
/**
 * @description Automatically refreshes specified custom functions
 * @author TheMaster https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453
 * @version 2.0.0
 * @changelog 
 *    Updated to support all custom functions and arguments
 *    Avoid eternal loops
 */

/**
 * @listens to changes in a Google sheet
 * @see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually
 */
function onChange(e) {
  /* Name of the custom function that is to be refreshed */
  const customfunctionName = 'SHEETNAMES',
    regexPattern = `=${customfunctionName}${String.raw`\(([^)]*?)?(?:,\s*?"RANDOM_ID_\d+")?\)`}`,
    replacementRegex = `=${customfunctionName}${String.raw`($1,"RANDOM_ID_${
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1
    }")`}`;

  /* Avoid eternal loop
   * Increase timeout  if it still loops
   */
  const cache = CacheService.getScriptCache(),
    key = 'onChangeLastRun',
    timeout = 5 * 1000 /*5s*/,
    timediff = new Date() - new Date(JSON.parse(cache.get(key)));
  if (timediff <= timeout /*5s*/) return;
  cache.put(key, JSON.stringify(new Date()));

  /* Following types of change are available:
   * EDIT
   * INSERT_ROW
   * INSERT_COLUMN
   * REMOVE_ROW
   * REMOVE_COLUMN
   * INSERT_GRID
   * REMOVE_GRID
   * FORMAT
   * OTHER - This usually refers to changes made by the script itself or sheets api
   */
  if (!/GRID|OTHER/.test(e.changeType)) return; //Listen only to grid/OTHER  change
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder(regexPattern)
    .matchFormulaText(true)
    .matchCase(false)
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .replaceAllWith(replacementRegex);
}
```

#### To Read:

- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)
- [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: OK. So to use this, I'd make an `onChange()` function like you have, substituting `SHEETNAMES` with the name of my custom function that needs to be re-run and replacing `GRID` with the change type I want the trigger to run on (ex `EDIT`). ... But is the `.replaceAllWith()` call correct? I think you'd need a back-reference to the group in original query like `'=SHEETNAMES(\1' + (Math.floor.....)`. And do you need to register the `onChange(e)` function, or does google do that automatically due to the function name/signature?

Comment: @bobpaul You need to register the trigger manually. See the `@see` link in the code. The ``sheetnames`` custom function  doesn't take any parameters that change the output(`e` is unused). So I didn't include a backreference. But if you have any non-optional parameters, you do need to change the regex as needed.

Answer (score 5):

As noted earlier:

> Custom Functions don't update unless it's arguments changes.

The possible solution is to create a checkbox in a single cell and use this cell as an argument for the custom function:

1. Create a checkbox: select free cell e.g. [A1], go to [Insert] > [Checkbox]
2. Make this cell an argument: `=myFunction(A1)`
3. Click checkbox to refresh the formula

Answer (score 4):

I use a dummy variable in a function, this variable refers to a cell in the spreadsheet.  Then I have a `Myfunction()` in script that writes a `Math.Random` number in that cell.

`MyFunction` is under a trigger service (Edit/Current Project Triggers) and you can choose different event-triggers, for example On-Open or time driven, there you can choose for example a time period, from 1 minute to a month.

Answer (score 3):

Since google app script is an extension of JS, functions should be able to handle more args than defined in function signature or fewer. So if you have some function like

```
function ADD(a, b) {
  return CONSTANTS!$A$1 + a + b
}
```

then you'd call this func like

```
=ADD(A1, B1, $A$2)
```

where $A$2 is some checkbox (insert -> checkbox) that you can click to "refresh" after you needed to change the value from the sheet & cell CONSTANTS$A$1

Answer (score 3):

Use a google finance function as a parameter. Like =GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:CADARS")

Those function force reload every x minutes

Comment: x = 20+ // minutes

Answer (score 2):

Working off of Lexi's script as-is, it didn't seem to work anymore with the current Sheets, but if I add the dummy variable into my function as a parameter (no need to actually use it inside the function), it will indeed force google sheets to refresh the page again.

So, declaration like: function myFunction(firstParam,dummy) and then calling it would be as has been suggested.  That worked for me.

Also, if it is a nuisance for a random variable to appear on all of your sheets that you edit, an easy remedy to limit to one sheet is as follows:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  e.source.getSheetByName('THESHEETNAME').getRange('J1').setValue(Math.random());
}
```

Comment: @Rubén it is very similar but with a good nuisance; instead of using the active sheet it uses a defined sheet name, improving your history

Answer (score 2):

There are several good answers here that did approximately, but not exactly, what I wanted.  I aggregated several of these answers.  I also used some new features that probably weren't available when this question was first asked.

The problem I wanted to solve was to have custom functions update in close-to-real time without manual refreshing and to have this be transparent to the Spreadsheet user (but not the extension programmer).

1. I created a new sheet called `update vars` and placed a named range on here for each update granularity I wanted.  For example, I created a named range `update_minute` for functions I wanted to automatically refresh every minute.  I hid this sheet for cleanliness.
2. For the functions I wanted to refresh I created an additional argument `forceUpdate` that would take an auxiliary variable (as many other answers here mentioned).  For example `function VPRICEUPDATE(fund, forceUpdate)` takes a Vanguard fund name to retrieve pricing data for and an auxiliary variable that only serves to invalidate the cache entry.
3. I created a named function in my spreadsheet called `VPRICE` that makes this auxiliary variable invisible to the user.  It takes a single argument, `fund`, and aliases to `VPRICEUPDATE(fund, update_minute)`.  Note that I would use `update_hour` in my alias if I wanted hourly updating.
4. Finally, to make this all work, the named range `update_XXX` has to be updated at every `XXX` interval.  I did this using a refresh function and the built-in triggers functionality.  For example, for the minute granularity I define:

```
function refresh_minute(){
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("update_minute").setValue(Date(Date.now()));
}
```

I then added a trigger to my project to call `refresh_minute()` every minute.  For functions that only need to be updated daily, I repeated this with a different timer set on the trigger.  It seems like you can also get daily update granularity using `TODAY()` as your auxiliary variable, but anything sub-daily is hard since Google makes it an error to reference `NOW()` in a formula.

Comment: Since you mentioned "the extension programmer", note that if you publish the code as an add-on, it won't be able to run triggers every minute. The highest frequency is "[once per hour at most](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)".

Answer (score 1):

## Highest performance

If you're fine with your script having permission to "See, edit, create, and delete **all** your Google Sheets spreadsheets", there's a much simpler and faster way to update a set of cells, than any other answers have mentioned so far.

The [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) lets you [write to multiple disjointed ranges at once](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets#write_values_to_multiple_ranges), using the [batchUpdate method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) and the operation is very fast (compared to `.setValues` / `.setFormulas`):

```js
function recalculateCells(recalcData) {
  const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  // Effectively, quote the values/formulas - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({
    data: recalcData,
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
  }, spreadsheetId);

  // Restore them as entered by the user - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({
    data: recalcData,
    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
  }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

`recalculationData` is an array of [objects](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values), where each object has two fields of interest:

- `range` - the cell to update, in [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#cell), e.g. `'My Custom Sheet'!B2:B2`
- `values` - the value to write, which should be the formula in the cell that you want updated (expressed as a bidimensional array with one row and one column, e.g. `[[cellFormula]]`).

You may notice that the spreadsheetId is superflous if the script is run for the current spreadsheet. However, `batchUpdate` required the spreadsheet ID because it can be run on any spreadsheet - that's why your script will need permission to "See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets". Please vote for [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270386310) to enable the Advanced Sheets Service to be scoped to only the current spreadsheet.

## Slightly lower performance

If you can't obtain the permission to "See, edit, create, and delete **all** your Google Sheets spreadsheets", you can use a RangeList to store the cells you want to refresh, then `.setValues()`, `flush(), and finally` .setFormulas()`and`flush()` again to force their recalculation.

```
const activeSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const rangesInSheet = [];

for (const range of sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges()) {
  const formulas = range.getFormulas();
  // Prepare a set of values to store in the cell briefly until
  // storing the formulas again. This serves two purposes:
  // 1. Provide visual feedback to the user
  // 2. More importantly, if the script gets terminated (e.g. due to
  //    Apps Scripts limits), the original formula is preserved as a value
  const recalcValues = [];
  for (let row = 0; row < formulas.length; row++) {
    recalcValues[row] = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < formulas[row].length; col++)
      recalcValues[row][col] = `[⚠ RECALCULATING ⚠] ` + formulas[row][col];
  }
  rangesInSheet.push({
    range,
    formulas,
    recalcValues
  });
}

// Flush all recalculation values first, THEN all formulas. This reduces the number of flush() calls from N*2 to 2.
for (const r of rangesInSheet) {
  // Storing noop formulas like =NOOP(...) or IFERROR(1/0, ...) didn't work because Sheets apparently caches the
  // result of the original formula and returns it right away to the noop. The only way to trigger calling the
  // custom functions again was to set the *values* of the cells, then setFormulas() again.
  console.log(`Storing raw values for ${r.range.getA1Notation()}...`);  // won't display the sheet name
  r.range.setValues(r.recalcValues);
}
SpreadsheetApp.flush();  // force changes to be written

for (const r of rangesInSheet) {
  console.log(`Restoring original formulas for ${r.range.getA1Notation()}...`);  // won't display the sheet name
  r.range.setFormulas(r.formulas);
  console.log('Formulas recalculated.');
}
// Force restoring original formulas; both flush()es are necessary
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

I've benchmarked this approach to 50+ cells per second, but haven't tried larger numbers of cell. For reasonable numbers of cells, it may be practically as fast as the `batchUpdate()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

another solution to the caching problem.

have a dummy variable in your method.
pass

```
Filter(<the cell or cell range>,1=1)
```

as the value to that parameter.

e.g.

```
=getValueScript("B1","B4:Z10", filter(B4:Z10,1=1))
```

the output of filter is not used. however it indicates to the spreadsheet that this formula is sensitive to B4:Z10 range.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore. You'll see the error "This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN()" if you try to do it in this way

Comment: You can invalidate the cache by [storing a `value` in the cell, then storing the formula again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77391841/1269037).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue creating a dashboard for work. Chamil's solution above (namely using Sheet's Filter function passed as the value to a dummy variable in your function) works just fine, despite the more recent comment from Arsen. In my case, I was using a function to monitor a range and could not use the filter on the same range since it created a circular reference. So I just had a cell (in my case E45 in the code below) in which I changed the number anytime I wanted my function to update:

```
=myFunction("E3:E43","D44",filter(E45,1=1))
```

As Chamil indicated, the filter is not used in the script:

```
function myFunction(range, colorRef, dummy) {
  variable 'dummy' not used in code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that feature explained by Henrique Abreu, you may try the **out-of-box spreadsheet function [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)** , that SQL liked query is what I use often in work 
on raw data, and get data as summary to a different tab, result data is updated in real time following change in raw data.

My suggestion is based on the fact that your script has not advanced work such as URL fetch, just data work, as without actual data read, I cannot give a precise solution with QUERY.

Regarding the **cache feature** mentioned by Henrique Abreu (I don't have enough reputation to comment directly under his answer), I did testing and found that:

1. looks there is no cache working, testing function's script shown below:

   function adder(base) {
   Utilities.sleep(5000);
   return base + 10;
   }

applying that custom function adder() in sheet by calling a cell, and then changed that cell value forth and back, each time I see the loading message and total time more than 5 seconds. 
It might be related to the update mentioned in this [GAS issue:](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3522)

> This issue has now been fixed. Custom functions in New Sheets are now context aware and do not cache values as aggressively.

2. the issue mentioned in this topic remains, my testing suggests that, Google sheet recalculate custom function each time ONLY WHEN

   - value DIRECTLY called by function is changed.

   function getCellValue(sheetName,row,col) 
   {
   var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
   return sh.getRange(row, col).getValue();
   }

   [image]
   A change of any value in yellow cells will lead to recalculation of custom function; the real data source value change is ignored by function.

   - function containing cell's location is changed in sheet. ex. insert/remove a row/column above or left side.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is to set up another cell somewhere in the spreadsheet that will be updated every time a new sheet is added. Make sure it doesn't update for every change but only when you want to do the calculation (in your case when you add a sheet). You then pass the reference to this cell to your custom function. As mentioned the custom function can ignore this parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I did not want to have a dummy parameter.  YMMV on this.

1  A cell that is a 'List of Items', one is "Refresh"

2  Script with 'onEdit', if the cell is "Refresh":

a)Empty out the document cache

b)Fill doc cache with external data (a table in my case)

c)For all cells with my 'getStockoData(...' custom function

- get the formula
- set '=0'
- set the fromula

d)Set the cell in (1) with a value of "Ready"

This does refresh the bits you want  BUT IS NOT FAST.

Comment: How exactly do you "empty out the document cache"?

Answer (score -1):

I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INB1Qwb8bPE&ab_channel=HayKel), from [1:44](https://youtu.be/INB1Qwb8bPE?t=104), and this worked for me.

You should use a specific update function, initialize a "current time" variable and pass this permanently updated variable to your custom function. Then go to Triggers and set up an "every-minute" time-driven trigger for the update function (or choose another time interval for updates).

The code:

```
function update() {
  var dt = new Date();
  var ts = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
  var cellVal = '=CustomFunction("'+ ts + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(cellVal);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add `GOOGLEFINANCE("eurusd")` as an additional argument to your custom function, like:

```
=myFunction(arg1, arg2, GOOGLEFINANCE("eurusd"))
```

Comment: Already mentioned  here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043635/

Answer (score -2):

As @Brionius said put an extra dinamic argument on the function. if you use now() you may have timeout problems make the update a little bit slower...

```
cell A1 = int(now()*1000)
cell A2 = function(args..., A1)
```

Comment: it doesn't work anymore. You'll see the error "This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN()" if you try to do it in this way

Answer (score -7):

If you have written a custom function and used it in your spreadsheet as a formula, then each time you open the spreadsheet or any referencing cell is modified, the formula is recalculated.

If you want to just keep staring at the spreadsheet and want its values to change, then consider adding a timed trigger that will update the cells. Read more about triggers [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers)

Comment: That would be just great, except it doesn't work... Reloading the page doesn't refresh the values. Moreover, deleting the cell and re-entering the same function call, still keeps the old value. If I call the same function exactly from another cell, it will show the new value, but not in the old cell.