# Get sheet name by formula in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have two sheets in my workbook:

- In `sheet1` in cell_1 by address `sheet1!A1` I store my data.
- In `sheet2` in cell_2 by address `sheet2!A1` I have the formula `=sheet1!A1`.

So the value of cell_2 always mirrors the value of cell_1. And the formula in cell_2 dynamically changes when I drag cell_1 on `sheet1` or rename `sheet1` (for example: '=sheet1!A1' transforms to '=newSheetName!B2').

I won’t get 'sheet name' 'N of column' and 'N of row' of cell_1 from the formula in cell_2. N of column I get by COLUMN(cell_1) and N of row I get by row(cell_1). To get the sheet name I tried a macro:

```
function getSheetName (link_to_my_cell){    
var myformula = link_to_my_cell.getFormula(); // and later I get sheet name by the myformula    
return (mySheetName);    
}
```

When I then set the cell_3 formula to `=getSheetName(link_to_cell_1)` it worked but if I rename `sheet1` this method does not refresh the value of cell_3. It works properly only if I start function `getSheetName` by trigger, maximum once per minute.

How can I get the sheet name in cell_3 from a formula in cell_2 'on the fly'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in google spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-spreadsheet)