# How to Force New Google Spreadsheets to refresh and recalculate?

Tags: google-sheets

There were some codes written for this purpose but with the new add-ons they are no longer applicable.

Comment: Not really, I meant refresh and recalc automatically

Comment: Rubén's answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127603/force-google-sheet-formula-to-recalculate helped me

Answer (score 63, accepted):

File -> Spreadsheet Settings -> (Tab) Calculation -> Recalculation (3 Options)

- On change
- On change and every minute
- On change and every hour
  *This affects how often NOW, TODAY, RAND, and RANDBETWEEN are updated.*

**but..**
.. it updates only if the functions' arguments (their ranges, cells) are affected by that.

**from my example**
I use google spreadsheet to find out the age of a person. I have his birth date in the format (dd.mm.yyyy) -> it's the used format here in Switzerland.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(K4:K), IF(TODAY() - DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(REGEXREPLACE(K4:K, "[.]", "/")), DAY(REGEXREPLACE(K4:K, "[.]", "/"))) > 0, YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(REGEXREPLACE(K4:K, "[.]", "/")) + 1, YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(REGEXREPLACE(K4:K, "[.]", "/"))), IF(LEN(K4:K) > 0, IF(TODAY() - DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(K4:K), DAY(K4:K)) > 0, YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(K4:K) + 1, YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(K4:K)), "")))
```

I'm using `TODAY()` and I did the recalculation settings described above. -> but no automatically refresh. :-(
It updates only if I change some value inside the ranges where the function is looking for.

So I wrote a Google Script (Tools -> Script Editor..) for that purpose.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetMaster = ss.getSheetByName("Master"); 
  var sortRange = sheetMaster.getRange(firstRow, firstColumn, lastRow, lastColumn);  

  sortRange.getCell(1, 2).setValue(sortRange.getCell(1, 2).getValue());
}
```

You need to set numbers for `firstRow`, `firstColumn`, `lastRow`, `lastColumn`

The Script gets active when the spreadsheets open, writes the content of one cell into the same cell again. That's enough to trigger the `TODAY()` function.

Look for more information on that link [from Edward Moffett: Force google sheet formula to recalculate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127603/force-google-sheet-formula-to-recalculate).

Comment: This seems to be the right answer and yet even when I do this, it doesn't automatically refresh. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: This doesn't work if the formula is only depending on the result of a custom function... would be nice if there was some way to just force sheets to recalculate everything as a one-off.

Comment: Instead of using a script, I figure you could just replace `IF(ISTEXT(…` by `IF(NOW()*ISTEXT(…`.  (This doesn’t change the value, as the `NOW()*` acts like `AND(TRUE;` due to implicit conversion to boolean.)

Comment: This may not work for the following reasons: make sure to replace the sheet name (here it is "Master") with your own sheet name; secondly, the `getRange()` function is defined as follows: [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) so instead of "`lastRow`, `lastColumn`" it should really be something like "`numRows`, `numColumns`"

Comment: Additionally, be careful to use `setValues()` - it will use the original output values, and will rewrite the original formulas with these values!!! See my answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 30):

What worked for me is inserting a column before the first column and deleting it immediately.
Basically, do a change that will affect all the cells in the worksheet that will trigger recalculation.

Comment: This did not work for me for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29283/how-to-refresh-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheet#comment137592_35970

Comment: This worked for me, it does recalc on column deletion. Thankx

Comment: This worked for me with a custom button: `function insertColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertRowBefore(1);
  sheet.deleteRow(1);
}`

Answer (score 24):

## Quick, but manual

#### Updating `NOW()`, `TODAY()`, `RAND()`, or `RANDBETWEEN()` formulas

**Press <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> on any empty cell** to immediately trigger a recalculation of formulas depending on `NOW()`, `TODAY()`, `RAND()`, or `RANDBETWEEN()` (in all Sheets of the whole Spreadsheet, as usual).

(If no empty cell is at hand, you can delete a filled cell instead and then undo that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.)

`INDIRECT()` formulas are unfortunately not updated like this by default.

#### Updating `INDIRECT()` formulas

You can update a (range of) cells of `INDIRECT()` formulas by pasting the range on itself:

1. Select cell/ range
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole current Sheet in step 1.. But for large Sheets then the other 2 operations can take several seconds each.
A trick to know when the process of copying a large range has finished:
Copy some single cell before copying your range: The single cell losing its dotted border will be your notification of the large copy finishing.

Answer (score 15):

Old question ... nonetheless, just add a checkbox somewhere in the sheet. Checking or unchecking it will refresh the cell formulae.

Comment: This doesn't recalculate Conditional Formatting, unfortunately.

Comment: This did not work for me for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29283/how-to-refresh-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheet#comment137592_35970

Answer (score 8):

### None of the existing answers worked for me, but this approach did.

**The problem**

I was seeing lots of cells say `#REF!`. These are cells in a sheet that I copied from another Google Sheet doc using "Copy to > Existing Worksheet". If I press Enter in any cell, it recalculates correctly, But I don't want to do that for millions of cells.

**My answer**

I ran this `recalcSheet()` script. It takes almost 0.5 seconds per cell, which is very slow but is faster than manually fixing each cell.

```js
function recalcSheet(){  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("put_your_sheet_name_here");  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename
  // var range = sheet.getSelection().getActiveRange();
  // var range = sheet.getRange('A6:D6');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();  
  recalcRange(range, spreadsheet);
}

function recalcRange(range, spreadsheet){
  // following structure of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123839/470749
  Logger.log('Range: ' + range.getA1Notation());
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var startCol = range.getColumn();
  Logger.log('row: ' + startRow);
  Logger.log('col: ' + startCol);
  Logger.log('numRows: ' + numRows);
  Logger.log('numCols: ' + numCols);

  for (var r = 1; r <= numRows; r+=1) {
    for (var c = 1; c <= numCols; c+=1) {
      var originalFormula = range.getCell(r, c).getFormula(); // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormula()
      Logger.log(`r,c ${r}, ${c}; originalFormula: ${originalFormula}`);
      if(originalFormula){
        range.getCell(r, c).setFormula('');
        //SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35970/27487
        range.getCell(r, c).setFormula(originalFormula);
      }
    }
  }
  spreadsheet.toast('Each cell in the range has been recalculated.', "Finished!"); // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String)
}
```

Comment: This approach works for programmatically refreshing cells, but for me it was necessary to also uncomment 'SpreadsheetApp.flush();', which did the trick.

Comment: It's much faster to use [batchUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77391841/1269037), at the expense of requiring permission to "See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to refresh a single row - press on its number to select it, then press `Delete` to delete the whole row and `Ctrl+Z` to immediately restore and recalculate it.

If you want to refresh the whole worksheet, press in the top left corner (where row numbers and column letters are crossed) to select everything and then `Delete` with `Ctrl+Z` again to restore and recalculate.

Comment: It works!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

When the problem is in the recalculation of an IF condition, I add `AND(ISDATE(NOW());condition)` so that the cell is forced to recalculate according to
what is set in the Calculation tab in Spreadsheet Settings as explained before.

This works because `NOW` is one of the functions that is affected by the Calculation setting and `ISDATE(NOW())` always returns `TRUE`.

For example, in one of my sheets I had the following condition which I use to check whether a sheet with name stored in `C1` is already created:

```
=IF(ISREF(INDIRECT(C$1&"!A1")); TRUE; FALSE)
```

In this case `C1="February"`, so I expected the condition to become `TRUE` when a sheet with this name was created, which didn't happen. To force it to update, I changed the Calculation setting and used:

```
=IF(AND( ISDATE(NOW()) ; ISREF(INDIRECT(C$1&"!A1")) ); TRUE; FALSE)
```

Comment: To auto-update e.g. an `=INDIRECT(C$1&"!A1")` without a surrounding `IF()`: `=INDIRECT(T(NOW())&C$1&"!A1")` (Explanation: `T()` filters for text type data;  `NOW()` is of datetime type (which is a number type), so not text type, so `T(NOW())` returns an empty string (`""`).  `&` concatenates that empty string, leaving the result unchanged (while working with strings).)

Answer (score 2):

Insert "checkbox". Every time you check or uncheck the box the sheet recalculates.  If you put the text size for the checkbox at 2, the color at almost black and the cell shade to black, it becomes a button that recalculates.

Comment: This did not work for me for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29283/how-to-refresh-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheet#comment137592_35970

Answer (score 2):

*I believe that the accepted answer has some major issues (as I mentioned in my comments), so I put together a better approach. This approach works for me regardless of whether the formulas contain any of the `NOW()`, `TODAY()`, `RAND()`, or `RANDBETWEEN()` functions or not. In fact, it works with custom functions as well.*

One thing to note is that this approach uses the `setFormulas()` function, which requires confirmation by the user. Therefore, instead of updating all the values only at the moment when the spreadsheet is open, the code below will create a new menu titled "Refresh" with a button "Refresh Data."

**Anytime you press this button, the desired data range will be refreshed** by re-pasting the original FORMULAS (not just values).**

Simply add this code to **Tools** -> **Script Editor** in your spreadsheet:

```java
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Refresh Data", functionName: "refreshData"});

  ss.addMenu("Refresh", menuEntries);
}

function refreshData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
  var myRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());  

  myRange.setFormulas(myRange.getFormulas());
}
```

Note that if you desire to refresh only a part of the spreasheet, change the values inside the `getRange()` function, as described in the [relevant documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

Answer (score 2):

I do it with a workaround:

1. Find and replace (CTRL+H).
2. Find "=" and replace with "=".
3. Be sure to check "search in formulas" in the options.

In this way you force recalculation for your sheet.

Comment: if you directly replace `=` with `=` it should still recalculate.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround that worked perfectly for me, I have a large Sheet with many "IMPORTRANGE" and many links to other sheets, so it happened that everytime someone updated the sheet, it wasn't showing anywhere else so I had to go tab by tab, selecting the whole thing, deleting and returning in order to update it but I just went to put the formula "=IF(TODAY()=TODAY()," before all my formulas (it was a pain the neck) and it finally worked, everything is updated in real time.

This took me some time but in the end I paid off.

Answer (score 0):

nothing worked, but I found a solution for myself - add an empty line in the working range of the formula (via the right mouse button), and then immediately cancel the action (Ctrl + Z). Profit! all formulas will be updated.

Answer (score -1):

Place your cursor on blank cell, press F4

Comment: What exactly is that supposed to do, [Redo](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en)?

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
function refreshCell() {
//refresh formula in cell A1

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
var r_Cell_1 = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).getFormula()

sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue("xx")
sheet.getRange(2,1,1,1).setValue(r_Cell_1)

var r_Cell_2 = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,1).getFormula()
sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue(r_Cell_2)
sheet.getRange(2,1,1,1).clearContent()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

I know that you are looking for an auto-refresh; perhaps some coming in here may be happy with a quick fix for a manual button (like the checkbox proposed above).  I actually just stumbled upon a similar solution to the checkbox: select the cells you want to refresh, and then press CTRL and the "+" key.  Seems to work in Office 365 v16; hope it works for others in need.

Comment: But this question is about Google Sheets, not Office 365. CTRL + causes Chrome to zoom in.