# Looping through cells in a range in Google Sheets with Google Script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, highlight

I want to write a script that allows me to highlight (background color) only some cells within a selected range, e.g., only cells in COLUMN 2 and ROW 2, even if I select the entire table.

Ex:
[image: How the script is supposed to work]

For example:

```js
For each cell in selected range {
 If selected cell[i][j] is within allowed range {
  cell background color = green
 };
};
```

The code I'm trying to finish:

```js
function BackgroundColor() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var cells = range.getValues();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
      if (range.getValues()[i][j] == '') {
        range.setBackground('#00B050').setFontColor('#ffffff')
      }
    }
  }
  range.setValues(cells);
};
```

I was able to make it in VBA:

```vb
Sub cmdGreen()

    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim GreenArrayCount As Integer
    Dim InteriorColor As Long, FontColor As Long
    Dim GreenArray() As Variant
    Dim BodyRange As String

    InteriorColor = VBA.RGB(0, 176, 80) 'interior in green
    FontColor = VBA.RGB(255, 255, 255) 'font in white
    GreenArray = Array("COLUMN 2", "ROW 2")
    BodyRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Address

    For Each Cel In Application.Selection.Cells
        If Not Intersect(Cel, Range(BodyRange)) Is Nothing Then
            For GreenArrayCount = LBound(GreenArray) To UBound(GreenArray)
                If (ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange(Cel.Column).Value _
                    = GreenArray(GreenArrayCount) Or _
                    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange(Cel.Row - 1, 1).Value _
                    = GreenArray(GreenArrayCount)) Then
                    Cel.Interior.Color = InteriorColor
                    Cel.Font.Color = FontColor
                End If
            Next GreenArrayCount
        End If
    Next Cel

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: please say a little more about the "allowed range". How are we supposed to know which cells to color green?

Comment: In my example, shown in the picture attached (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCJhe.png), the allowed range is the COLUMN 2 and ROW 2. Only the cells in this range can be colored, if they are selected.

Comment: Is the 'allowed range' **ALWAYS** R2 and C2?  If that's the case, there's no need for all of the code.  Just set the range to R2 and C2, then set Background.

Comment: In this, example, yes. But I want to block people from setting the background of the cells outside this range. This is a sharerable sheet.

Comment: I've added an equivalent VBA code that makes the same in Excel. Thats what I want, but for Google Sheets.

Comment: Writing an Excel macro and asking for it to be translated to Google Apps Script is outside the SO scope. What's wrong with your current code? You don't mention any problems or errors in it. You don't mention how you have tried modifying it and failed to obtain desired results.

Answer (score 7):

Modified code:

```
function BackgroundColor() {

  var okColumn = [3, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var startCol = range.getColumn();

  for (var i = 3; i < numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k <= 4; k++) {
        if ((startRow + i == okRow) || (startCol + j == okColumn[k])) {
          range.getCell(i+1,j+1).setBackground('#00B050').setFontColor('#ffffff')
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There are doubtless ways to improve performance, but this should do the trick.

```
function BackgroundColor() {
  var okRow = 2;
  var okColumn = 2;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();

  //Logger.log('Active Range: ' + selection.getActiveRange().getA1Notation());

  var range = selection.getActiveRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var startCol = range.getColumn();
  //Logger.log('row: ' + startRow);
  //Logger.log('col: ' + startCol);
  //Logger.log('num row: ' + numRows);
  //Logger.log('num col: ' + numCols);

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
      if ((startRow+i == okRow) || (startCol+j == okColumn)){
        //Logger.log('found: ' + i+' '+j);
        range.getCell(i+1,j+1).setBackground('#00B050').setFontColor('#ffffff')
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Note that the range is 0 based, but getCell is 1 based.
Note too that my ok row and column here are based on actual rows and columns, not on their labels. In your example okRow would be 4 and okColumn would be 3.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jeremy! It worked and I was able to modify it to fit my needs. Below, I've post the modified code.