# how to automatically Generate Daily report from Data using query formula in google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

initially, i use `sumifs` to generate daily report, but its problematic as our staffs have to change dates daily within the formula, i want a formula that can automatically pull out data for each day.
I already Tried `today()` function , but it i wont be able to save data for daily sheet, the second sheet shows exactly what i want using `sumifs` formula.  is there any query formula that can pull out the data on daily basis? i already solved the weekly report using query formula.

[here is a link to my google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RqxXkpH-LJc4sDJzi7o_Gr9YM-vfNrpiQY3-yye7kAY/edit#gid=0)

```
={QUERY(A1:I," select A, B, sum(D),sum(F),sum(H),sum(F)-sum(H) WHERE A =date '2021-08-02' and B is not null group by A,B order by sum(D) desc limit 1000 label A 'Dates',B 'Customers',sum(D) 'TOTAL RMB', sum(F) 'Total Naira',sum(H) 'Total Received',sum(F)-sum(H)'Net Balance' "); {" ","Total",sumif(A2:A,date(2021,8,2),D2:D),sumif(A2:A,date(2021,8,2),F2:F),sumif(A2:A,date(2021,8,2),H2:H),sumif(A2:A,date(2021,8,2),F2:F)-sumif(A2:A,date(2021,8,2),H2:H)}}
```

how can i possibly automatically generate daily report using query formula without having to manually edit the date daily

Comment: When you say you've tried `TODAY()`, Have you tried it like this `WHERE A =date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`  ??

Comment: yes i did, the problem is that we often need to check yesterdays balance or  the day before, is it possible to create a button the can pass the date to it?

Comment: Have you tried [changing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29448960/3160483) the recalculation setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that maybe you just need a cell reference where users can input any date then retrieve the desired results:

I've chosen `J1`, but you can have the user enter a date wherever you want:

```
WHERE A =date '"&TEXT(J1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
```

This method does not required users to modify the formula, in fact you can even protect the formula from editing and let user edit `J1` only (if necessary)

(Same thing for your `SUMIF`)

Comment: thanks so much, this is what i was looking for

Comment: i will create a dropdown menu, so that they can just select the date without having to type it out

Comment: Actually when formatting a cell with DATE, if you double-click on it you can see the monthly calendar showing up, so no need really for a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are recalculated frequently, you have to pass a constant date to it.

Comment: yes i know, how do i pass the date  into the formula without touching the formula, lets say i want see data within a specific date range, how can i do it without touching the formula

Comment: It seems you objective has changed from that (daily report) described in the question. As for daily report, you may consider to include the date in a cell (i.e. `A1`) and refer to `A1` in the `QUERY` formula.