# Running a function from its relative row number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet where I want to use a custom function, like this
[image: spreadsheet]

In the end there will be an arbitrary number of these example fields in the spreadsheet, and I need to count the ever changing order numbers for each customer field.

I have made an onEdit trigger, but that seems to run the function across the entire datasheet producing an error:

> "The starting row of the range is too small. at countOrders(Code:25)".

I think the problem is the function is not tied to the cell I put it in, and the code runs relative to the cell.

```
/*
This function counts the rows above the current row, up until the predefined header
*/

function countOrders() {

  //CHANGEABLE SETTINGS
  var HEADERTEXT = "Odrenummer"      //What kind of text to look for
  var COLUMN = 1                     // What column to search for the header
  var ACTIVEPOS = 5                  // Where to look for the active/passive field

  // Open current spreadsheet, and get the rownumber where the function is run
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell()
  var rowPointer = cell.getRow()

  // Initialize the count variabel,
  // and make the rowPointer point to the row above the function
  var count = 0
  rowPointer--


  // Count rows between 
  while (data != HEADERTEXT){
    var range = sheet.getRange(rowPointer,COLUMN)
    var data = range.getValue()

    rowPointer--

    // only count up if the ordernumber is not empty
    if (data != ""){
        count ++

    }

  }
  // Is the status active?
  var state = sheet.getRange(rowPointer,ACTIVEPOS);
  state = state.getValue()


  // Return the counted rows, minus the header
  if (state == "Aktiv"){
    return count-1
  }

  return 0

}


function onEdit(e) {
  countOrders();
}

function onChange(e) {
  countOrders();
}
```

I expect the output to update if I append more orders, or if I change the status of the field from "Aktiv" to "Passiv".

I also expect to be able to copy paste the area to produce a second one below, making the code work relative to its position.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the result in B3 and then the answer will always be `sheet.getLastRow()-4`. And with  reference to your onEdit() issue, scripts are tied to projects and projects have access to all sheets.  If you want to eliminate sheets then use something like this `if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='SheetName')return;` in your onEdit() function.

[onEdit() event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up followign the answer to this question:

[Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet)

This gave me what i wanted, i dont like that i need the ever changing random number in my sheet, but i just put it far to the right.