# Custom function won't refresh as inputs are changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a custom function that finds the value of another cell and displays it. When the source cell is changed, the function does not reflect.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wfFe__g0VdXGAAaPthuhmWQo3A2nQtSVUhfGBt6aIQ0/edit?usp=sharing

Refreshing google sheets

```
function findRate() {
  var accountName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue(); //determine the account name to use in the horizontal search
  var rateTab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Rates'); //hold the name of the rate tab for further dissection
  var rateNumColumns =rateTab.getLastColumn(); //count the number of columns on the rate tab so we can later create an array
  var rateNumRows = rateTab.getLastRow(); //count the number of rows on the rate tab so we can create an array
  var rateSheet = rateTab.getRange(1,1,rateNumRows,rateNumColumns).getValues(); //create an array based on the number of rows & columns on the rate tab
  var currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow(); //gets the current row so we can get the name of the rate to search
  var rateToSearch = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(currentRow,1).getValue(); //gets the name of the rate to search on the rates tab
  for(rr=0;rr<rateSheet.length;++rr){
    if (rateSheet[rr][0]==rateToSearch){break} ;// if we find the name of the 
      }
  for(cc=0;cc<rateNumColumns;++cc){
    if (rateSheet[0][cc]==accountName){break};
      }
  var rate = rateSheet[rr][cc] ; //the value of the rate as specified by rate name and account name
  return rate;
}
```

If I change a rate in the rate tab, I need the custom function to recognize the new rate and update its value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet)

Comment: Custom functions are deterministically evaluated. If one takes no arguments, then it never needs to be recalculated, according to Google. The solution? Pass arguments! You clearly rely on cells in the spreadsheet for the calculation, so make it explicit e.g. `C4: =FINDRATE(A4)`. Then when A4 changes, this formula in C4 will too.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to recalculate the custom function of `=findRate()`, when the cells of the sheet name of `Rates` are edited.

If my understanding is correct, how about adding the following sample script? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Solution:

In order to recalculate the custom function, in this answer, the formula of `=findRate()` is overwritten by the script running with the OnEdit event trigger (in this case, it's the simple trigger.). By this, the recalculate is executed. But, when the formula is directly replaced by the same formula, the recalculate is not executed. So I used the following flow.

1. Retrieve all ranges of cells which have the formula of `=findRate()` from the sheet of "Projected Revenue".
2. Clear the formulas of the ranges.
3. Put the formulas to the ranges.

By this flow, when the cell of the sheet of "Rates" is edited, the custom function of `=findRate()` is recalculated by automatically running `onEdit()`.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. **Then, please edit the cells of sheet name of `Rates`. By this, `onEdit()` is automatically run by the OnEdit event trigger.**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Rates" && range.rowStart > 1 && range.columnStart > 1) {
    var sheetName = "Projected Revenue"; // If you want to change the sheet name, please modify this.
    var formula = "=findRate()";// If you want to change the function name, please modify this.

    var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var ranges = sheet.createTextFinder(formula).matchFormulaText(true).findAll().map(function(e) {return e.getA1Notation()});
    sheet.getRangeList(ranges).clearContent();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setFormula(formula);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- `onEdit(e)` is run by the OnEdit event trigger. So when you directly run `onEdit(e)`, an error occurs. Please be careful this.
- In this sample script, as a sample, even when the row 1 and column "A" of the sheet of "Rates" are edited, the custom function is not recalculated. If you want to modify this and give the limitation of range you want to edit, please modify the above script.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

The proposal from [TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893480/custom-function-wont-refresh-as-inputs-are-changed/56895168?noredirect=1#comment100347712_56895168) was reflected to the script. When `sheet.createTextFinder(formula).matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith(formula)` can be used, also I think that the process cost will be much reduced. But in my environment, it seemed that the formulas are required to be cleared once to refresh the custom function, even if `flush()` is used. So I have proposed above flow.

But, now I could notice a workaround using `replaceAllWith()` of TextFinder. So I would like to add it. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Replace all values of `=findRate()` to a value in the sheet of `Projected Revenue` using `replaceAllWith()`..

   - In this case, as a test case, the formulas are replaced to `sample`.
2. Replace `sample` to `=findRate()` using `replaceAllWith()`.

By this flow, I could confirm that `=findRate()` is recalculated. And also, it seems that `flush()` is not required for this situation.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. **Then, please edit the cells of sheet name of `Rates`. By this, `onEdit()` is automatically run by the OnEdit event trigger.**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == "Rates" && range.rowStart > 1 && range.columnStart > 1) {
    var sheetName = "Projected Revenue";
    var formula = "=findRate()";
    var tempValue = "sample";

    var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.createTextFinder(formula).matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith(tempValue);
    sheet.createTextFinder(tempValue).matchFormulaText(true).replaceAllWith(formula);
  }
}
```

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. Yes. using ``replaceAllWith()`` can lead to the reduction of the process cost, as you say. But at first, in my environment, it seemed that the formulas are required to be cleared once to refresh the custom function, even if ``flush()`` is used. So I have proposed above flow. But, now I found a workaround for using ``replaceAllWith()``. So I added a sample script. Could you please confirm it? In this case, it seems that ``flush()`` is not required. By your proposal, the script became more simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tanaike , thank you so much for your assistance in this!! This updates in the exact way that I needed. I'm wondering if you have a recommendation for a clean way of editing the code you provided to update the findRate() function across multiple sheets? In reality, I have a "Projected Revenue" tab for multiple accounts (over a dozen)

Comment: @Alex F Thank you for replying. Although I cannot understand about your detail situation of `` I have a "Projected Revenue" tab for multiple accounts (over a dozen) ``, when you want to refresh ``findRate()`` of other sheets in a Spreadsheet, when you modify ``var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName);`` to ``var sheet = e.source;`` of the added script, ``findRate()`` of all sheets in the Spreadsheet is refreshed. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.