# How to identify onChange event source/author in the google sheets via google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets, service-accounts, eventsource

I need to determine if the `onChange` event in Google sheets is triggered by a Google service account or by a person, because I want to process the changed data only if the trigger source was human-made direct editing, otherwise stop processing.

I tried to identify it with `Session.getActiverUser()`, but, although the change is through the service account, shows my own email address.

I can not find anything on the Internet, nor in the Google documentation.

PS: to be more clear, I did bidirectional syncing from Firebase Realtime Database to Sheets and vice versa. Therefore, to avoid redundant update cycle, I want to stop processing as soon as change/update happens on behalf of the Service Account.

Or maybe there is some other way to avoid loop problem. I will be glad of any help

Comment: Are the users in your same domain? I mean those who execute `getActiveUsers()`

Comment: No one executes the code, it gets automatically triggered whenever something changes in sheet. I need to somehow get identity of change author to decide further actions

Comment: What about getEffectiveUser?

Comment: Still the same, returns my email. But let me try one more time with skydriver logging

Comment: I just checked and Session.getEffectiveUser() returns my email too :(

Comment: Check changeType and `user` in `e` and see if there's a difference.. try cooper's answer too- see if `e` has any different params that can be used to delineate.

Comment: If all that fails, try [getUserAgent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#getuseragent) or try showing a prompt/dialog in the browser. If  there's a human, dialog should show, else it should timeout. None of it is ideal, but onChange triggering on script executions is not a documented feature.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62807921

Comment: I think your suggestions made something. User info is hidden when service account makes an update. `AM
Warning
The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity.` Check it out https://i.imgur.com/xgNFXIf.png

Comment: @wol Great. If you can confirm it works, add a answer. See [answer]. @Cooper was actually suggesting the same thing to you- to look into `e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically it is a bit a hacky way, but it works.

As @TheMaster suggested `onChange` event parameter `e` contains `user` node, which in case of Service Account is empty, thus could be used to distinguish change event sources.

[image: devtools console screenshot]