# Google Sheets OnChange script to rename cell as sheet name not working

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, onchange

I tried inserting the code from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807234/how-to-get-auto-refresh-google-spread-sheet-custom-cell-fuction-from-google-app), but I am getting an error message and I am not familiar enough with .gs code to understand what the issue is from the debugger.

Currently I have a basic script that puts the Google sheet name into the cell tat has =sheetname() in it. It is working and it seems to be on some daily refresh because it eventually will update the cell names if I change the sheet name, but I want it to refresh faster/when a change happens. I added an OnChange Trigger as well as copy-pasted the code from the question response above. Is someone able to help me figure out what`s wrong?

Thank you!!!

[Screenshot of debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3syV.jpg)

Comment: Please include sample sheet with expected output.

Comment: @JasonE. here is a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EZ-8H_9MwNDjPgvgnw5chctjhojZeWazhu5cM1X9-tc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you tell me the error message you are getting when trying to run your script? Also, please provide your complete code along with the sheet that you shared.