# How to make google-api play nice with custom functions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

When using a [custom spreadsheet function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), this intermittently fails when accessing the spreadsheet using the `Google-API`. Anyone solved something like this?

I am accessing a Google sheet using python. An except showing how this is set up follows. Spreadsheet-specific data and authentication have been omitted:

```py
from google.oauth2.service_account import (
    Credentials as ServiceAccountCredentials,
)
from googleapiclient import discovery

credentials = json.loads(jsonText)
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_service_account_info(
            info=credentials,
            scopes=SCOPES,
        )
gService = discovery.build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)
request = gs.spreadsheets().get(
                spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                ranges=ranges,
                includeGridData=True,
            )
response = request.execute()
sheet_data = response["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]
num_cols = 10
for row_idx in range(4, len(sheet_data)):
    row = sheet_data[rowIdx]
    for col, colHeader in zip(row["values"], col_headers):
         gValue = col["formattedValue"]
         ...
```

I have created a custom function that is used in a large number of cells in the spreadsheet, called by e.g. `=DeadlinePassed(DATEVALUE("2024-03-23"))`:

```js
/**
 * @param {Date} inputDate Date to check
 * @return Date or ''
 * @customfunction
 */
function DeadlinePassed(inputDate) {
  // Get the current date and subtract one day
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
  
  // Check if the input date is valid
  if (!inputDate || 
       (Object.prototype.toString.call(inputDate) !== "[object Date]" && 
        Object.prototype.toString.call(inputDate) !== "[object Number]")) {
    return '';
  }

  // If the input date yesterday or after, return it. Otherwise return ''.
  if (inputDate >= yesterday) {
    return inputDate;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Instead of returning the expected value, I get `col["effectiveValue"]["errorValue"]`:

> 'type': 'NAME'
> 'message': "Unknown function: 'DeadlinePassed'."

The fact that this is intermittent is driving me crazy. It'll work for a while and then stop working on the same spreadsheet with exactly the same data.

Comment: In your situation, who is the owner of the Spreadsheet? By the way, what is `["function variables"]` of `col["effectiveValue"]["errorValue"]["function variables"]`? And, if my understanding is correct, I think that `DATEVALUE("2024-03-23")` is the number value. So, `Object.prototype.toString.call(inputDate)` returns `[object Number]`. By this, `return '';` is run. Is this your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I am the owner of the spreadsheet. `["function variables"]` of `col["effectiveValue"]["errorValue"]["function variables"]` is data returned from the Google API call (in a `dict`). the `DATEVALUE` function returns the date value, which is a value used by Google Sheets to represent dates. While it is a number, its type is "[object Date]"

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I am the owner of the spreadsheet.`, in this case, the owner of the Spreadsheet is your Google account which is not the service account. Is my understanding correct? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about `["function variables"]`. Can you provide the official document of this property `["function variables"]`? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: About `the DATEVALUE function returns the date value, which is a value used by Google Sheets to represent dates. While it is a number, its type is "[object Date]"`, in your situation, what result did you obtain with `=DeadlinePassed(DATEVALUE("2024-03-23"))`? When I tested it, an empty value was returned. So, I asked about it. But, I think that this might not be the essence of your current issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. If the date value is drawn from a cell (e.g. `=DeadlinePassed(A2)` that has a formatted date value, its type is "[object Date]", whereas if done through an inline use of the `DATEVALUE` function, it returns "[object Number]". I simplified the example in the question. In reality, the `DeadlinePassed` function is called on formatted date values in other cells. As you pointed out, that is not the essence of the issue I am grappling with, but useful anyway and I have modified the sanity checking to permit "[object Number]" types as valid.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood about `=DeadlinePassed(DATEVALUE("2024-03-23"))`. When `DATEVALUE("2024-03-23")` is put into "A2" and `=DeadlinePassed(A2)` is used, the cell value of "A2" is `[object Date]`. About your current issue, even when the cell value is showing the correct value with no error, `Unknown function: 'DeadlinePassed'.` is returned when your Python script is run. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I apologise for including the function variables in the `dict` scope. They are, in fact, only a debugger artefact (now removed). The `ErrorValue` documentation can be found here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ErrorValue 
I am using the service account to access the API.

Comment: Your understanding of the issue is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `ErrorValue`, I understand it. About your current situation, also I understand it. But, when I tested your situation, unfortunately, I cannot replicate it. When I use `gs.spreadsheets().get()`, the showing cell value is correctly returned with no error. I apologize for this situation. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to test it.

Comment: I have just tested it and it works again. As I stated in the question, this is an intermittent problem. Sometimes it will work perfectly. Other times, it will error out claiming not to know about the custom function. Even I cannot reliably reproduce the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `this is an intermittent problem`, although I'm not sure whether this is included in your expected direction, for example, how about refreshing the custom functions before you run `gs.spreadsheets().get()`? But, I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: To support @Tanaike and other community members helping you. You said it was intermittent then there are a series of tests you've done for this. Do you mind sharing the data set you used for that just to get an overall overview of your case? What changes during the time you are testing? I particularly want to know if some of the dates include date values that is interchanging on the month's and day's places.

Comment: @Babanana Unfortunately, I cannot share the data it is operating on as it is confidential. Dates are always entered in ISO format to avoid juxtaposing the month and day fields. The same data (unmodified) can work one day and then not the next day. Could it be a timeout issue with the backend database not keeping up with demand? I am not sure how the Google API system works with handling custom functions in the backend.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. I have looked through the API for keywords "refresh" and "recalculate", and I have not found any obvious way to "refresh" the custom functions in the spreadsheet before calling `gs.spreadsheets().get()`. Could you elaborate on what that would involve?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About refreshing the custom function, the process of this can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895168). This is Google Apps Script. But, the process is the same. When you want to refresh the custom function using Python, please clear the formula and put the formula again. By this, the custom function is refreshed. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I understand now. Basically, clear the cell and then re-create it. I have tried this solution in the past. Unfortunately, once the API does not recognise the `DeadlinePassed` function as valid, this problem persists, even when a cell is updated. I have also tried re-downloading the whole sheet. Occasionally, this will break the API out of its funk, but most of the time, the problem will persist.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Unfortunately, once the API does not recognise the DeadlinePassed function as valid, this problem persists, even when a cell is updated.`, I deeply apologize that my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike Nothing to apologise for. Thanks for taking the time to attempt to help ☺

Comment: Mark, I was able to experience what you are referring about and was intrigued I tried to research more about what is happening. As a result I was able to find this Google Support case about a bug that is doing exactly what is happening to you. [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324452568](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324452568) here is the link. You can access the link to get more information and also get updates for the steps taken to resolve this.

Comment: @Babanana Thanks! It's a relief that you are able to reproduce this behaviour. Thanks too for the bug report. I have commented on it and will keep an eye on progress.

Comment: I have this same issue.