# How do I recurse this formula over a range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm setting up a spreadsheet that pulls data from an API when given a string. This requires a custom function to pull and parse the API. I would like to use one instance of the formula to cover the entire spreadsheet, but adapting the Google example code:

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(DOUBLE); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    return input * 2;
  }
}
```

doesn't return any values.

This is my current code. The code itself will not work without an API key from the website in question to replace my `'PRIVATE'` authorization token.

```
function COASTER(input) {

 /**
 * Returns coaster stats from name.
 *
 * @param {name} input The value or range of cells to use.
 * @return Coaster statistics.
 * @customfunction
 */

  if (input.map) {            // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(COASTER); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {

    // Call the Captain Coasters API
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://captaincoaster.com/api/coasters?name=" + input ,{"headers": {'X-Auth-Token': 'PRIVATE' }});

    // Parse the JSON reply
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);

    var results = data["hydra:member"];
    var output = []

    results.forEach(function(elem) {
      output.push([elem["@type"],elem["materialType"]["name"],elem["length"],elem["speed"],elem["manufacturer"]["name"],elem["seatingType"]["name"],elem["inversionsNumber"],elem["height"],elem["status"]["name"],elem["park"]["name"],elem["score"],elem["rank"]]);
    });
    return output
  }
}
```

I expected the values produced by the formula `COASTER(B2:B3)` to exist, but I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "map" from undefined. at COASTER(Captain Coaster API:11)`, line 11 being the beginning of the `if` statement.

Comment: Writing the push to a new array solved my row issue. I've edited the post to show the remaining conundrum I have.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your sheet? Are any cells in `B2:B3` empty; if not, what are their values? Have you tried running this with values from a test function (e.g., simply making a `function test() { Logger.log(COASTER('test input')); }`)? Also, fair warning, [updating values from a custom function will cause some other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet); you might find it easier to just do things in GAS on a trigger.