# TypeError: Cannot read property 'regularMarketPrice' in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Updated:
After changing `data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData.item(code).regularMarketPrice.raw` to `data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData[code].regularMarketPrice.raw` I am still getting the error message `[21-06-23 14:47:53:398 PDT] TypeError: Cannot read property 'regularMarketPrice' of undefined at marketPrice(Code:6:91)` and when I tried running Logger.log it would never do anything. Also, when I go to the spreadsheet and use formula marketPrice("CL=F") it shows the current price but if you wait an hour and enter the same formula in the cell below you get two different prices. What would be the reason for the first formula not updating.

Old:
This was working fine for the first few days and now I'm getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'regularMarketPrice' of undefined (line 6, file "Code"). In google sheets I use the formula =marketPrice("CL=F").

```
function marketPrice(code) {
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var regularMarketPrice = data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData.item(code).regularMarketPrice.raw
  return regularMarketPrice
}
Object.prototype.item=function(i){return this[i]};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have delopped this way to retrieve informations from yahoo finance, and it worrks well as you can see here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zZhtvO74kE__k5N2VfbWypnfWt82lSwDkMKk9PL1bg4/copy

```
//Mike Steelson     
Object.prototype.item=function(i){return this[i]};    
function marketPrice(code) {
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var regularMarketPrice = data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData.item(code).regularMarketPrice.raw
  return regularMarketPrice
}
```

Moreover, if you want to refresh the data, check or uncheck the box in B2.

```
=marketPrice(A2,$B$1)
```

You can use it inside a script as following :

```
function localTest(){
  var code=('CL=F')
  var market_Price = marketPrice(code)
  Logger.log(market_Price)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike Steelson! That works amazing.

Comment: is there a way to keep the historical's of price updates so that I can put a sparkline beside the price?

Comment: yes, take a new copy of  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zZhtvO74kE__k5N2VfbWypnfWt82lSwDkMKk9PL1bg4/copy then reresh by the custom menu or put a trigger on historic function

Comment: @ Mike Steelson, thank you! I used the on edit trigger so that it will add when checkmark is clicked. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

As discussed in the comments below, `TypeError` occurs when the user runs the `marketPrice` function in the Apps Script.

Supposedly, `marketPrice` should be used as **Custom Function**, where the user will input the function name into a cell in Google Sheet with a parameter and then Google Sheet will pass the parameter value to Apps Script function and execute it.

When a user runs the function directly to Apps Script, the value of `code` in `marketPrice(code){}` is automatically undefined.

Since the parameter `code` is undefined, the script can only fetch `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/` which has no data for `regularMarketPrice`.

To force your script to have value in `code`. You can use the default parameter value.

**Example:**

```
function marketPrice(code="CL=F") {
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var regularMarketPrice = data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData.item(code).regularMarketPrice.raw
  return regularMarketPrice
}
Object.prototype.item=function(i){return this[i]};
```

**Note:** This will also work if you use it as a custom function. Google Sheet will just overwrite the default value of `code`.

For custom functions not updating/refreshing automatically you can check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet/17347290#17347290).

### References

- [JavaScript Default Parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)
- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: I made the above changes and in my Logs I have this error message. [21-06-23 12:03:37:160 PDT] TypeError:Cannot read property 'regularMarketPrice' of undefined at marketPrice(Code:6:91)

Comment: Could you print the value of `data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData.item(code)` and attach it in your post above?

Comment: I tried running logger.log for the regularMarketPrice but it never would display anything

Comment: Could you try Logger.log(data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData)? The code from your post and the one I posted are both working on my end.

Comment: I tried that too and still nothing return other than the error message in the Logs. I opened up a new google sheet and used the =marketPrice("CL=F") and put the above code in AppsScript and it's showing the correct price. Still getting the error message though when I try to run it directly from the script page. When I try to use debug it acts like it wants to display something and then nothing happens.

Comment: When you run it directly in the Apps Script, the value of `code` in your function marketPrice is null. This will cause your script to fail. Unlike when you use it as custom function,  Google Sheet will pass a value to marketPrice(code) parameter.

Comment: Is there a way to make the value of my `code` not null? I also noticed the price change within the past hour. The one from an hour ago show $73.27 and the new one I just typed below it show $73.08. Would you happen to know why it is not updating?

Comment: @MitchellBivens - Could you update your post above with the information you've provided here so I can update my answer.

Comment: Yes. Updating now

Comment: I updated the original post and explained changes made and issues I'm currently having after updates.

Comment: Thank you @Nikko J for your help as well!