# Google Sheet - Force a linked spreadsheet to refresh

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pulling a realtime quote from "spreadsheet B" into "spreadsheet A" through:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url";"A1").
```

For some kind of reason the referenced cell in "spreadsheet A" is blank until I open "spreadsheet B". This will kickstart the realtime quotes and they will be updated also in "spreadsheet A".

It's worth mentioning that "spreadsheet B" is using a custom "apps script" in order to pull in those realtime cryptocurrency quotes.

Is there a way to have the calculations in "spreadsheet B" kickstarted only by accessing "spreadsheet A"?
Thanks all!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `a custom script` of `It's worth mentioning that "spreadsheet B" is using a custom script to pull in those quotes.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Try running the script everytime you open spreadsheet A

Comment: What calculations have to be made on Spreadsheet B? Can you give more information on your workflow?

Comment: If I try to import the script into the new spreadsheet it won't run for some reason, while it works in the original spreadsheet but it has to be triggered manually - by the simple opening of the spreadsheet. 
I wonder if there's a script or function which can trigger a script present in another spreadsheet (Not sheet)

Comment: Custom function in spreadsheet A right? Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet

Comment: Have you thought of using a [Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) on she spreadsheet b that triggers the custom apps script script?

Comment: Like Kessy says, you could try to trigger the Spreadsheet B script using the time-driven triggers. They will not be real-time though. You could try an onOpen or onEdit connected to spreadsheet A but that would require that whoever is using Spreadsheet A also has access to Spreadsheet B.
Also worth noting that if Spreadsheet B is updating frequently, importrange may be unable to keep up with the changes.