# A way to refresh =ImportJSON every 5 minutes with API call

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, refresh, custom-function

I'm trying to refresh all the cells that have an ImportJson call in my google sheets every 5 minutes utilizing a trigger. I'm using a call such as this for many cells however each call is different due to which product I'm getting and whether I'm collecting a sellPrice or buyPrice :
=ImportJSON("https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=insertAPIhere","/products/DARK_ORB/quick_status/buyPrice", "noTruncate,noHeaders")

I've tried searching around and running loops through the apps script to replace the links but it doesn't update the actual data within the cell.

[Here is an example of how my cells are setup:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp7if.png)

I looked for solutions as listed below:

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/161096847/importing-json-data-efficiently?hl=en
This one I tried adding the URLs and it would throw an error

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylH_7i4hLwc&feature=youtu.be
This one I looked at to attempt to utilize the update function, however it doesn't support multiple URLs with the update function listed in the description.

Comment: What was the error

Comment: Error
Exception: Invalid argument: https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[insertAPIhere]","/products/DARK_ORB/quick_status/sellPrice
ImportJSONAdvanced
@ Code.gs:131
ImportJSON
@ Code.gs:95
(anonymous)
@ read.gs.gs:10
refreshJSON@ read.gs.gs:9

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399/refresh-data-retrieved-by-a-custom-function-in-google-sheet