# Google Sheets: calculate colored cells and recalculate it when something changes in the column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a task to count the number of different colored cells in google tables, I found a solution on the internet and it works, but I need it to recalculate itself when something changes in the table, please help. Below is the function I use for counting

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

Comment: From what I know, the feature to `recalculate itself when something changes in the table` is currently not possible with custom functions. You may review the question [`Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341399), as it contains things that you may utilize as a workaround for this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using onEdit(e) trigger on your function. Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)